# How do you uninstall apache2 when it thinks it's already uninstalled?

Tags: apache2, upstart

When I originally did

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2*
```

I hadn't stopped apache. After it didn't work I googled and found somewhere that you have to take a special step of stopping apache first.

I guess it didnt remove it from upstart or something. I removed /etc/apche2 after a few restarts. It doesnt show up on localhost now but it still consumes port 80.

I am actually totally psyched about digging through documentation and trying random commands on my linux box until the thing that isnt working this time stops happening.

Does anyone on the internet know some commands I can try on ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: If you had done `sudo apt purge apache2` to also remove the config files! Please run that command

Comment: After that you can also try `sudo apt autoremove` to remove dependencies of apache2 you don't need without apache2 anymore.

Comment: did both and restarted. localhost apache2 start page is back. ill just reinstall the os